# Jquery Autocomplete token input does'nt work in safari and chrome

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

Autocomplete token input box works properly in IE and Firefox but it doesn't work in safari and crome.

this is a part of code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=path%>/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
//for auto complete
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jqueryAutocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jqueryAutocomplete/jquery.ajaxQueue.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/jqueryAutocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" />

    $j(document).ready(function(){

    $j("#id_CBRERegion").tokenInput(path + "fetchAutoCompleteResult.do?method=regionList", {
            theme: "facebook",
            queryParam: "search",
            minChars: 1,
            preventDuplicates: true,
            hintText:"CBRE Region",
            prePopulate: selRegCode              
        });
        $j('#id_CBRERegion').prev().find("input").blur();
        registerAutoEvent('id_CBRERegion','id_CBRERegion_Temp');
        if(document.getElementById('id_CBRERegion').value != "") {
            $j('#id_CBRERegion_Temp').hide();
        } else if(document.getElementById('id_CBRERegion').value == "") {
            $j('#id_CBRERegion_Temp').next().hide();
        }   
    });
```

Please suggest..

Comment: Please post your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Please provide a link to the version of the autocomplete plugin you are using as most will confuse this with the jQuery UI autocomplete otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just visited http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ in Chrome and Safari and it works.

Many factors could be causing the problem, from css to data.

Best way to resolve and learn the function.

- start from a simple example off the site
- Add in your bits slowly until you see it fail.